# csv_name is not a member of arma

Tags: c++, csv, armadillo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mlpack/core.hpp>
int main()
{
    arma::mat dataset;
    arma::field<std::string> headers;
    dataset.load(arma::csv_name("house_to_rent.csv", headers));    
    return 0;
}
```

When running this I am getting the error `csv_name is not a member of arma`. Have I messed up installation somewhere?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Editor: VSCode

[mlpack](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/tree/master/src/mlpack)

Arma Version: 9.800.4

Comment: If this is your whole code you have to include headers.

Comment: The compiler can't automagically know the headers. You have to include them.

Comment: You should also include `string` and `armadillo`

Comment: still same error...

Comment: What version of Armadillo do you use? There is no `csv_name` in Armadillo 8.6

Comment: I've used the same code before, this is a fresh installation, I can't figure out what's going wrong here...

Comment: As far as I can see there is no `csv_name` in Armadillo 9.8. You can find it in Armadillo 9.9: https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/9.900.x/include/armadillo#L196 but not in Armadillo 9.8: https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/-/blob/9.800.x/include/armadillo

Answer (score 1):

There is no `csv_name` in Armadillo 9.8. You have to update Armadillo to at least version 9.900.